# Javascript: one function to check individual checkboxes in the same group, and store the answer individually

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, generated-code

I am very new to js, and I have been searching for this answer for days. I have a little personal project I'm working on, and it includes checkboxes.

I have a function that is supposed to help generate code to copy/paste/save as a new html. Since I'm new to js I am having problems getting the verification of the checkboxes to work properly, and to have it check each checkbox one at a time (not as a group/array), then to *save the individual value* to apply it to the function that generates the code so that it can be +added+ in the correct place.

I have this [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/sujiya/edit?html,js,output) for you to view, that might help explain it better, especially if you press the 'Get Code' button.

I know there is a better way to get it to do the code, and I can't seem to get what I do have to generate properly. I keep *seeing the code when I press the 'Get Code' button* instead of the checkmark I want to see.

I am somewhat good (not great) at html and css only.

I would appreciate any help you can offer.

The html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SCV</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="inputRelations" id="inputRelations">
  <h2>Relations</h2>
    <div id="rel">
     <table class="rel2"><tr><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="crush" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="crush">Crush</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="love" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="love">Love</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="engaged" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="engaged">Engaged</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="married" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="married">Married</label>
       </td></tr><tr><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="friends" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="friends">Friends</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="buddies" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="buddies">Buddies</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="known" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="known1">Known</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="bff" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="bff">BFF</label>
       </td></tr><tr><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="steady" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="steady">Steady</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="family" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="family">Family</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="enemy" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="enemy">Enemy</label>
       </td><td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="unknown" value="&#9745;"/>
       <label for="unknown">Unknown</label>
       </td></tr>
       </table>
   </div>
   <nav id="box2" class="hide"><table id="menu3"><tr><td rowspan="2" id="soft">
   <textarea name="source2" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
   </td><td>
   <input type="button" value="Get Code!" onclick="javascript:generateRelations();"></td>
   <td rowspan="2" id="softA">
   <img src="./forSCV/icons/relations.png" alt="Relations" title="Relations" id="arrow" onclick="toggle('box2');">
   </td></tr><tr><td>
   <input type="button" value="Test Code" onclick="javascript:displayRelations(this.form);">
   </td></tr></table></nav>
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS.

```
function generateRelations() {
var feelingsFor = document.inputRelations.feelingsFor.value;
var relationType = document.inputRelations.relationType.value;
var dailyA = document.inputRelations.dailyA.value;
var dailyB = document.inputRelations.dailyB.value;
var lifetimeA = document.inputRelations.lifetimeA.value;
var lifetimeB = document.inputRelations.lifetimeB.value;

// I need it to check if these individual checkmarks are checked then save
// the value to insert into the outputRelations section of this function
// (generateRelations)

// There has to be a more condensed way to do this.
var crush = function() {
  var c1 = document.inputRelations.crush;
    if (c1.type == 'checkbox' && c1.checked === true){
  return c1.value;}
    else {
  return '';
    }
};

var love = function() {
  var l1 = document.inputRelations.love;
    if (l1.type == 'checkbox' && l1.checked === true){
  return l1.value;}
    else {
  return '';
    }
};

var engaged = function() {
  var e1 = document.inputRelations.engaged;
    if (e1.type == 'checkbox' && e1.checked === true){
  return e1.value;}
    else {
  return '';
    }
};

var married = function() {
  var m1 = document.inputRelations.married;
    if (m1.type == 'checkbox' && m1.checked === true){
      return m1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var friends = function() {
  var f1 = document.inputRelations.friends;
    if (f1.type == 'checkbox' && f1.checked === true){
      return f1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var buddies = function() {
  var b1 = document.inputRelations.buddies;
    if (b1.type == 'checkbox' && b1.checked === true){
      return b1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var known = function() {
  var k1 = document.inputRelations.known;
    if (k1.type == 'checkbox' && k1.checked === true){
      return k1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var bff = function() {
  var bA = document.inputRelations.bff;
    if (bA.type == 'checkbox' && bA.checked === true){
      return bA.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var steady = function() {
  var s1 = document.inputRelations.steady;
    if (s1.type == 'checkbox' && s1.checked === true){
      return s1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var family = function() {
  var f1 = document.inputRelations.family;
    if (f1.type == 'checkbox' && f1.checked === true){
      return f1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var enemy = function() {
  var e1 = document.inputRelations.enemy;
    if (e1.type == 'checkbox' && e1.checked === true){
      return e1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

var unknown = function() {
  var u1 = document.inputRelations.unknown;
    if (u1.type == 'checkbox' && u1.checked === true){
      return u1.value;}
    else {
      return '';
    }
};

// I want to add the checkbox values in this section.
// I need individual values to do so. Not a list.
outputRelations = "<a name='relations'></a>\n<div id='easy'>\n<h2>Relations</h2>\n
<div id='rel'>\n<div id='rela'>\n<table class='rel'><th colspan='2'>My feelings towards 
"+feelingsFor+"</th><tr><td>Relation Type:</td><td class='white'>"+relationType+"</td>
</tr><tr><td>Daily:</td><td class='white'>"+dailyA+" / "+dailyB+"</td></tr><tr><td>
Lifetime:</td><td class='white'>"+lifetimeA+" / "+lifetimeB+"</td></tr></table>
<table class='rel1'><tr><td class='white'>"+crush+"</td><td>Crush</td><td class='white'>
"+love+"</td><td>Love</td><td class='white'>"+engaged+"</td><td>Engaged</td><td class='white'>
"+married+"</td><td>Married</td></tr><tr><td class='white'>"+friends+"</td><td>Friends
</td><td class='white'>"+buddies+"</td><td>Buddies</td><td class='white'>"+known+"
</td><td>Known</td><td class='white'>"+bff+"</td><td>BFF</td></tr><tr><td class='white'>
"+steady+"</td><td>Steady</td><td class='white'>"+family+"</td><td>Family</td><td class='white'>
"+enemy+"</td><td>Enemy</td><td class='white'>"+unknown+"</td><td>Unknown</td></tr>
</table>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n";

document.inputRelations.source2.value = outputRelations;

return outputRelations;
}
```

I got the answers I was wanting, but I still have one more. Is there a better/condensed way of handling nested functions?

Comment: Define "problems" and "work properly". And the code should be in the question itself, a link is not enough.

Comment: I mean that instead of storing the value for function generateNightlife to generate the code, it is instead sending the code I am using to the function. Also that I cannot figure out a single code for this instead of having to type it over and over.

Comment: I am missing something that is probably very simple, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit I found out your errors.

1. when you use

   > class='white'>"+crush+"Crush

it must be used like `crush()`

```
class='white'>"+crush()+"</td><td>Crush</td>
```

because you are calling a function, that will return the value and not a function

2. change these

   var crush = function() {
     var c1 = document.inputRelations.crush;
     var c2 = c1.length;
       if (c2[i].type == 'checkbox' && c2[i].checked === true);
         return c2.value;
   };

change it to

```
var crush = function() {
  var c1 = document.inputRelations.crush;
    if (c1.type == 'checkbox' && c1.checked === true);
      return c1.value;
};
```

you can't use c2[i].value
c2[i] is not in a loop, and it is just a number it is not the checkbox, c1 is the checkbox. c2 is just the checkbox.length, you don't need that.
I hope that helps. If you need more guidance let me know.

Comment: not as an array, then I cannot get the individual checkbox value to +add+ in the right place of the function I want it in.

Comment: checkbox[i] insode of the forloop gives you the individual checkbox. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I can't even test if that will work until I can figure out why the generated code just prints the function out rather than giving me a value.

Comment: what is this push function, can we see it?

Comment: that was me trying two different ways to hopefully get it to work. It didn't. I have a JS Bin link above you can view.

Comment: ok let me take a look at it and I will see what I can do. It's hard to read and not very clear

Comment: I figured it out I will repost my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, that was making me crazy not being able to figure out what I was doing wrong. :)